# Problem, Conflicting bools on OnCollisionStay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Problem, when i press E to instanciate the Hole object, and them press F to instanciate the Tree, ev
if the player is still colliding with the Hole, when i press F the holeColliding turns false.

public class CreateHole : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public GameObject gameObject2;
public GameObject gameObject1;
public bool holeColliding;
public Transform playerPosition;
public bool facingRight1 = true;
public Vector3 holePosition;
public bool treeColliding;
void Update()
{
    facingRight1 = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().facingRight;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && holeColliding == false && facingRight1 == true)
    {
        Instantiate(gameObject1, playerPosition.position + new Vector3(0.6f, -1f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && holeColliding == false && facingRight1 == false)
    {
        Instantiate(gameObject1, playerPosition.position + new Vector3(-0.6f, -1f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F) && holeColliding == true && treeColliding == false)
    {
        Instantiate(gameObject2, holePosition + new Vector3(0f, 0.5f), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}

 void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
 {
    if(other.tag == "Hole")
    {
        holePosition = other.transform.position;
        holeColliding = true;
        Debug.Log("true");
    }
    else
    {
        holeColliding = false;
        Debug.Log("false");
    }
    if(other.tag == "Tree")
    {
        treeColliding = true;
    }
    else
    {
        treeColliding = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`gameObject2` seems not to be tagged "Hole" so your `else` in `OnTriggerStay` sets `holeColliding = false`...

Since [`OnTriggerStay2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay2D.html) is executed every frame but only for one Collider at a time you will always end up with your `bool`s messed up! 
*(Unfortunately the API isn't really clear about whether it is called only for one other object or for each, I'ld assume/expect the later - but it doesn't really matter here)*

---

I would rather not use a repeated `OnTriggerStay2D` but split it into [`OnTriggerEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) and [`OnTriggerExit2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerExit2D.html). This makes sense anyway since otherwise you can enter a hole, leave it but `holeColliding` would stay `true` forever!

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.CompareTag("Hole"))
    {
        holePosition = other.transform.position;
        holeColliding = true;
        Debug.Log("true");
    }
    else if(other.CompareTag("Tree"))
    {
        treeColliding = true;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.CompareTag("Hole"))
    {
        holeColliding = false;
    }
    else if(other.CompareTag("Tree"))
    {
        treeColliding = false;
    }
}
```

---

Note as already in the code above I would recommend to rather use [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html) instead of directly comparing strings with `==`. `CompareTag` throws an exception if the provided tag is misspelled or doesn't exist at all. A "bug" that would get silently hidden by `==` simply returning `false` all the time costing you development time and nerves ;)

---

Two other points in general:

- **Never** use `GetComponent` in `Update` or repeated at all - it is a quite expensive call. Rather store the reference **once** and reuse it!
- You check the Input for `E` twice which is also redundant and needles expensive. Since in both code blocks you do almost the same you can even shorten it more using the [`?` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) (which is basically a shorthand for `if - else` when assigning only one single variable differently)

I would modify your code to

```
// Best would be you already reference this via the Inspector
// Then you can skip the GetComponent completely
[SerializeField] private PlayerMovement playerMovement;

private void Awake ()
{
    // Otherwise get it at runtime and store it for later
    if(! playerMovement) playerMovement = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
}

void Update()
{
    // Now reuse the already stored reference
    facingRight1 = playerMovement.facingRight;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && !holeColliding)
    {
        // Since in both code blocks you do exactly the same
        // .. the only changing is a `-` you can shorten your code a lot
        var x = 0.6f * (facingRight1 ? 1 : -1);

        Instantiate(gameObject1, playerPosition.position + new Vector3(x, -1f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F) && holeColliding && !treeColliding)
    {
        Instantiate(gameObject2, holePosition + Vector3.up * 0.5f, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, solved the major problems i was having and teached me new things, the only problem im having now,that was the reason for me to use OnCollisionStay, instead of Enter and Exit, is that snice the holes are close to each other, when the Collider of the player is colliding with the hole making it true, and i turn the player, and the collider is on top of another hole the bool keeps being false, since the collider leaved the hole when turning.

Comment: hm in this case you could add them to a list and only reset to `false` once **all** holes left